# Using regex to find any last occurrence of a word between two delimiters

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the following test string:

Start_Get_Get_Get_Stop_Start_Get_Get_Stop_Start_Get_Stop

where _ means any characters, eg: StartaGetbbGetcccGetddddStopeeeeeStart....

What I want to extract is any last occurrence of the Get word within Start and Stop delimiters. The result here would be the three bolded Get below.

Start__Get__Get__**Get**__Stop__Start__Get__**Get**__Stop__Start__**Get**__Stop

I precise that I'd like to do this only using regex and as far as possible in a single pass.

Any suggestions are welcome

Thanks'

Comment: "I precise that I'd like to do this only using regex and as far as possible in a single pass." -- why? And what flavour of regex is this? (since different versions support different constructs)

Comment: Regex because I need to extend an existing generic tool developed using regex. It uses .NET Framework System.Text.RegularExpressions, but I cannot say exactly which flavour it is... Probably Microsoft's one.

Comment: Microsoft has (at least) two different flavours, but saying it's .NET Framework should be enough to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get(?=(?:(?!Get|Start|Stop).)*Stop)
```

I'm assuming your `Start` and `Stop` delimiters will always be properly balanced and they can't be nested.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks' Alan Moore.

Comment: Hi Alan, I've tried this variant of your solution: Get(?=(?:(?!Get).)*Stop) and it seems to be working too. What is the need for the alternation (Get|Start|Stop) since (assuming delimiters are correctly balanced as you mention) the requirement is to have no other Get between the searched Get and the suffix ?

Comment: `Start` is to prevent matching a `Get` that's not between delimiters, like `Get_Start_Stop`.  As for `Stop`, suppose there's a whole bunch of text after the last `Stop`.  You don't want the `.*` to go all the way to the end, only to have to backtrack most of that distance to match the `Stop`.  Lookaheads can be slippery; it's worth a little extra care to make sure they only look as far ahead as you need them to.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it with two passes. The first pass find the word "Get", and the second pass count the number of occurrences of it.

Comment: Thanks' PolyThinker, but I can handle it in two steps as you suggest, but I wonder if it would be possible in a single pass...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "Start_Get_Get_Get_Stop_Start_Get_Get_Stop_Start_Get__Stop" | awk -vRS="Stop" -F"_*" '{print $(NF-1)}'
Get
Get
Get
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe:

```
(?<=Start(?:.Get)*)Get(?=.Stop)
```

That requires variable-length lookbehind support, which not all regex engines support.
It could be made to have a max length, which a few more (but still not all) support, by changing the first `*` to `{0,99}` or similar.

Also, in the lookahead, possibly the `.` should be a `.+` or `.{1,2}` depending on if the double underscore is a typo or not.

Comment: AFAIK, the `{0,99}` trick only works in Java (i.e., it supports bounded variable-length lookbehind).  But you're in luck: the OP is using .NET, one of the two flavors that support *unbounded* lookbehind (the other being JGSoft).

Answer (score 0):

With Perl, i'd do :

```
my $test = "Start_Get_Get_Get_Stop_Start_Get_Get_Stop_Start_Get_Stop";
$test =~ s#(?<=Start_)((Get_)*)(Get)(?=_Stop)#$1<FOUND>$3</FOUND>#g;
print $test;
```

output:

```
Start_Get_Get_<FOUND>Get</FOUND>_Stop_Start_Get_<FOUND>Get</FOUND>_Stop_Start_<FOUND>Get</FOUND>_Stop
```

You should adapt to your regex flavour.